# Spring Security OAuth - Can it consume JWT tokens from Keycloak

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, jwt, keycloak

In Spring Security OAuth, can it consume/work with JWT tokens that were generated from a user authenticating with Keycloak?  Keycloak's open-id far as that goes, but it all seems to be really similar.  I'm still trying to understand the dividing line and also what's similar or same with this.

Basically I'd like to authenticate separately in a REST client then use the token in the Authorization header for REST calls to some web services.  There seems to be some JWT stuff in in the Spring Security OAuth, so I'm wondering I can actually use that instead of the Keycloak Spring stuff?  Are there any examples of this out there?  (I'd love to use the Spring security checks on different methods in my controller)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Keycloak Spring adapter and still rely on Spring Security annotations for controller security. The main purpose of the Keycloak Spring adapter is simplify the integration with Keycloak for interactive login and also to correctly map JWT access token claims into the Spring Security authentication context.

Reading through the [Spring Security OAuth2 documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html), I get the impression that it's not quite ready out of the box to handle OpenID Connect JWT access tokens. However, it's customizable so it could most likely be made to work.

My advice for now is to stick with the Keycloak Spring adapter if you're using Keycloak as your OIDC server. It will save you time and it's well tested with Keycloak.

Comment: I ended up going with the Keycloak adaptor for Spring Boot.  Along with it, I updated KeycloakUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider from https://github.com/Smartling/smartling-keycloak-extras in order to have UserDetails object.  It's a shame you can't go the all-Spring route, but there's definitely pieces missing.  Bummed I didn't get to use the token store stuff.

Comment: For folks landing here, I'd invite you to check out the Spring Security 5.1+ release, which ships with OIDC using JWTs. The link here is for the current latest version (5.2.0.RC1): https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login